# How to backup site excluding folders using PHP

Tags: php, backup

I want to take backup of my website files and want to exclude some folders/files.
I looked for a solution in an older post and tweaked a bit as described below:

```
<?php
/*
 * PHP: Recursively Backup Files & Folders to ZIP-File
 * (c) 2012-2014: Marvin Menzerath - http://menzerath.eu
 * contribution: Drew Toddsby
*/

// Make sure the script can handle large folders/files
ini_set('max_execution_time', 600);
ini_set('memory_limit','1024M');

$dir = '/home/user10/public_html';
$HKfilename = date("Y-m-d-H-i"); 
$saveto = "/home/user10/public_ftp/file_bkup-$HKfilename.zip";
$exclude = array("$dir/cache","$dir/images", "$dir/media");

// Start the backup!
zipData($dir, $saveto, $exclude);
echo 'Files backup created: file_bkup-$HKfilename.zip';


// Here the magic happens :)
function zipData($source, $destination, $exclude) {
    if (extension_loaded('zip')) {
        if (file_exists($source)) {
            $zip = new ZipArchive();
            if ($zip->open($destination, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)) {
                $source = realpath($source);
                if (is_dir($source)) {
                    $iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source);
                    // skip dot files while iterating 
                    $iterator->setFlags(RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
                    $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($iterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
                    foreach ($files as $file) {
                        if ( in_array($file, $exclude) ) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        if ( is_file($file) ) {
                            $p = pathinfo($file);
                            if ( in_array($p['dirname'], $exclude) ) {
                                continue;
                            }
                        }
                        $file = realpath($file);
                        if (is_dir($file)) {
                            $zip->addEmptyDir(str_replace($source . '/', '', $file . '/'));
                        } else if (is_file($file)) {
                            $zip->addFromString(str_replace($source . '/', '', $file), file_get_contents($file));
                        }
                    }
                } else if (is_file($source)) {
                    $zip->addFromString(basename($source), file_get_contents($source));
                }
            }
            return $zip->close();
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I'm getting below error, while executing the script.

```
[15-Dec-2017 12:17:02] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method RecursiveDirectoryIterator::setFlags() in /home/user10/public_ftp/filebackup.php on line 32
```

If I comment this code,

```
$iterator->setFlags(RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
```

zip file is generated with file name file_bkup-2017-11-22-20-39.zip.KDzpTi (last 6 chars changes on each attempt). However, this zip file does not contain all files/folders. Also, this zip file contains the folders which are specified in exclude array.

Comment: You added line that generates error, but you did not add the error itself.

Comment: Error from the error_log has been updated in the post...